# Show that $F = \{a + b\sqrt{5} | a, b ∈ \mathbb Q\}$ is a field

Tags: field-theory

**Question:**

> Show that $F = \{a + b\sqrt{5} | a, b ∈ \mathbb Q\}$ is a field under the
>   operations - addition and multiplication where addition is given by:
>   $(a + b\sqrt{5})+(c + d\sqrt{5}) = (a + c) + (b + d)\sqrt{5}$ and
>   multiplication is given by $(a + b\sqrt{5})(c + d\sqrt{5}) = (ac+5bd)
>  + (ad+bc)\sqrt{5}$

**My work:**

Since $\mathbb Q$ is a field, addition and multiplication defined by $(a + b\sqrt{5})+(c + d\sqrt{5}) = (a + c) + (b + d)\sqrt{5}$ and  $(a + b\sqrt{5})(c + d\sqrt{5}) = (ac+5bd) + (ad+bc)\sqrt{5}$ will produce elements in $F$ therefore $F$ is *closed under multiplication and addition*.

Because $F$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ the operation on $F$ correspond to the usual operations on $\mathbb R$ so the *associative*, *commutative* and *distributive* conditions are inherited from $\mathbb R$

The *additive identity* is $0+0\sqrt{5}$ because $(a + b\sqrt{5})+(0+0\sqrt{5}) = (a + b\sqrt{5})$

The *multiplicative identity* is $1+0\sqrt{5}$ because $(a + b\sqrt{5})(1+0\sqrt{5}) = (a + b\sqrt{5})$

The *additive inverse* is $((-a) + (-b)\sqrt{5})$ because $(a + b\sqrt{5})+((-a) + (-b)\sqrt{5}) = 0$

The *multiplicative inverse* is where I went wrong, and not quite sure what to do, I think I have to find something such that $(a + b\sqrt{5})\times? = 1 = 1+0\sqrt{5}$ I thought of just putting $$\frac{1+0\sqrt{5}}{a+b\sqrt(5)}$$ but I was told this wasn't right so not sure what else to do.

If anyone can help me with checking the *multiplicative inverse* condition that would be really appreciated.

Comment: You need to show that $?$ is an element of $F$. So, can you show that this $\frac{1+0\sqrt{5}}{a+b\sqrt{5}}$ can be expressed as $c+d\sqrt{5}$, where $c,d \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to simplify that expression so that it has the form:
$$
\alpha + \beta\sqrt{5}
$$
for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb Q$. Indeed, we can do this via conjugates:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a + b\sqrt 5}
&= \frac{1}{a + b\sqrt 5} \cdot \frac{a - b\sqrt 5}{a - b\sqrt 5} \\
&= \frac{a - b\sqrt 5}{a^2 - 5b^2}  \\
&= \underbrace{\frac{a}{a^2 - 5b^2}}_{\in ~ \mathbb Q} + \underbrace{\frac{-b}{a^2 - 5b^2}}_{\in ~ \mathbb Q}\sqrt 5
\end{align*}
To finish this off, can you see why the denominator $a^2 - 5b^2$ is never zero if $a$ and 
$b$ are not both zero?

Comment: Thanks Adriano! I didn't even think of using the conjugates stuff =p

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar trick as in complex numbers. Note that $(a+b\sqrt5)(a-b\sqrt5)=a^2-5b^2$, so $\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt5}=\frac{a-b\sqrt5}{a^2-5b^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Every non-zero element of $\mathbb Q[√5]$ is a unit. And other proof you have already shown. That's why we can conclude it's a field.

Answer (score 0):

What if there is a condition $a^2+b^2\neq 0?$ How to prove closure under multiplication?