# Show that $F=\{a+b\sqrt3\;|\;a,b ∈Q\}$ is a field

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

We just started Linear Algebra 2 and this is the question that was given to me:

> Show that $F=\{a+b\sqrt3\;|\;a,b ∈Q\}$ is a field under operations ⊕
>   and ⊙, where ⊕ is given by $(a+b\sqrt3)\;⊕\;(c+d\sqrt3) =
> > (a+c)+(b+d)\sqrt3$ and ⊙ is given by $(a+b\sqrt3)\;⊙\;(c+d\sqrt3) =
> > (ac+3bd)+(ad+bc)\sqrt3$.

My answer started off something like this.

> Addition and multiplication on $F$ will generate elements in $F$.
>   Therefore $F$ is closed under addition and multiplication. Since the
>   components are also elements of $Q$, associative, commutative and distributive properties will also hold.

And now I have to prove the existence of identity elements and existence of inverses.

> Additive identity : $(a+b\sqrt3)\;⊕\;0 = (a+0)+(b+0)\sqrt3=a+b\sqrt3$
>
> Multiplicative identity : $(a+b\sqrt3)\;⊙\;1 = (a∙1)+b\sqrt3 = a+b\sqrt3$ - **For this part however, I'm not sure if I did this
>   correctly. I know I should be following the directions that they gave
>   to multiply, but the value is simply 1. What would I have to do in
>   this scenerio?**

Then I had to prove the inverses, and the additive inverse was easy enough, I proved it like so.

> Additive inverse: $-(a+b\sqrt3) = (-a-b\sqrt3)$
>
> Multiplicative inverse: ??

So I got lost at this point and I searched around, and found a [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985020/show-that-f-a-b-sqrt5-a-b-%E2%88%88-mathbb-q-is-a-field), but I have a few questions. (I'm going to change the posts numbers to relate with my question)

1. In the post, the additive inverse was written as $0+0\sqrt{3}$, but my initial thought was to simply write $0$. Why is the other way the right way to write it? In the end isn't $0+0\sqrt{3}$ equal to zero regardless?
2. Same goes for the multiplicative identity portion, it was written as $1+0\sqrt{3}$, but my thought was to simply write $1$. Why is $1+0\sqrt{3}$ the proper way to write it (I'm assuming)

And lastly, I'm wondering if anyone has a good place where I could read/watch a video on how to do these type of questions. Normally I refer to my textbook but for some reason this chapter, and this chapter alone, isn't in our textbook.

Thank you

Comment: you can write `\Rightarrow` instead `=>`

Comment: My mistake haha the arrow came out of random, didn't mean for that to be there in the first place

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420797/show-that-the-set-mathbbq-sqrtp-ab-sqrtp-a-b-p-in-mathbbq-sqrt)

Comment: You could use commands to make the arrows, it just use $=$, since that is what you actually mean.

Comment: Last time I checked there were infinitely many rational numbers, so the resulting field is not finite. Nor is there a vector field (= a concept from multivariable calculus and its abstractions) in sight. So I removed tags [tag:finite-fields] and [tag:vector-fields]. Please be careful in picking tags.

Answer (score 0):

Some details just needed to be filled as you pointed out the *multiplicative* *inverse* $(a+b\sqrt{3})^{-1} = \dfrac{1}{a+b\sqrt{3}}= \dfrac{a-b\sqrt{3}}{a^2-3b^2}= \dfrac{a}{a^2-3b^2} + \dfrac{-b}{a^2-3b^2}\sqrt{3}$. The rest of your work is fine.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's okay to simply write out "The additive inverse is $0$" rather than $0+0\sqrt{3}$

And there was another question similar to this, but F was written as $[a,b]$. How would the multiplicative inverse of that be found? I know now you just take the conjugate for my previous question, but what about for $[a,b]$

Comment: @HelloMellow No, you should write "The additive inverse is $0+0\sqrt3$". That's because the additive inverse is _always_ called $0$, and the fact that you know what it should be called does not demonstrate that the element exists, or which element it really is.